# Issue requests from local Google App Engine devserver with TLSv1.2

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, tls1.2

I'm running an AppEngine on Java 1.7, using the Spring framework. I need to do request to the [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#intro) , which requires TLSv1.2 when doing a request. This works fine when deploying the application to the Google environment, but it refuses to use this protocol when running the server locally. It gives the following error:

> Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please
>   initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later. You can learn more
>   about this at https://stripe.com/blog/upgrading-tls.

I'm using IntelliJ, AppEngine SDK version 1.9.42 in combination with Maven. I've tried adding build options in multiple places (-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2), in the IntelliJ Run/Debug configuration, in the XML JVM flags, in the dev_appserver.py file, but none of them worked. How can I enable TLSv1.2 in my Java 7 local development server, and talk to the Stripe API?

Answer (score 0):

From the blog entry referenced in the error log:

> You can proactively check whether your Stripe integration is ready,
>   and how to upgrade, by following the steps on our [TLS deprecation
>   page](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-stripe-integration-from-tls-1-0-to-tls-1-2).

And from that link which points to [How do I upgrade my Stripe integration from TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2?](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-stripe-integration-from-tls-1-0-to-tls-1-2) you can find [the Java-specific instructions](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-stripe-integration-from-tls-1-0-to-tls-1-2#java):

> You can determine whether your Java integration is affected from the
>   Java version you are running, and the stripe-java version you are
>   using.
>
> You can find your Java version by running `java -version` at the
>   command line, and your stripe-java version by looking for the version
>   number in your jar file’s name, for example `stripe-java-1.40.0.jar`
>   or by finding the version of the Stripe dependency in your POM file.
>
> If you are running Java
>
> - version 1.6, you will need to upgrade to at least Java version 1.7, and stripe-java version 1.36.0.
> - version 1.7, and you have a stripe-java version earlier than 1.36.0, you will need to upgrade to at least stripe-java version 1.36.0.
> - version 1.8, you will not need to change anything.
>
> You can upgrade your stripe-java version by [downloading a new
>   jar](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java), or by upgrading the version number in your POM, and
>   rebuilding your project.
>
> You can upgrade your Java version by [downloading a new copy](https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp), or
>   installing a newer version of OpenJDK.